# Docker Compose FASTAPI microservices can't communicate

Tags: rest, docker-compose, localhost, microservices, fastapi

I have two services, **predict** and **preprocess** that should communicate over REST.

I can use the preprocess_service as follows:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://0.0.0.0:3000/preprocess' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "feature_1": 1,
  "feature_2": 2
}'
```

I dockerized both services and want to call the preprocess service inside the predict service - this does not work.

The error msg says:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: /preprocess (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb53b37ad70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

What am I doing wrong?

**Project Structure:**

---

Project:

- predict_service

  - main.py
  - requirements.txt
  - Dockerfile
- preprocess_service

  - main.py
  - requirements.txt
  - Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml

---

Dockerfile in predict_service:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app 

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Dockerfile in preprocess_service:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app 

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  predict_service:
    image: dockerplaygroundpredict:latest
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  preprocess_service:
    image: dockerplaygroundpreprocess:latest
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:8000"
```

Finally, this is the main.py in the predict_service that should communicate with the preprocess_service:

```py
app = FastAPI(
    title="SIMPLE FASTAPI POC",
    description="----> PREDICTION",
    version="0.1"
    )


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    """Health check."""
    return {"message": HTTPStatus.OK.phrase, "status-code": HTTPStatus.OK,}

@app.post("/predict", tags=["Prediction"])
def predict(request: Request, sample: FeatureSample) -> Dict:
    """Predict output for sample input."""

    
    headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    }

    json_data = {
        'feature_1': 1,
        'feature_2': 2,
    }

    preprocessing_response = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:3000/preprocess', 

                                           headers=headers, json=json_data)


    return {"message": HTTPStatus.OK.phrase, "status-code": HTTPStatus.OK, "data": {"predictions": "Dummy_Prediction"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are running in different containers, they can't access each other on the local IP 0.0.0.0. You instead use the container names (`predict_service` and `preprocess_service`) as hostnames, so you should post to `'http://predict_service:3000/preprocess'`.

Comment: I just changed:     preprocessing_response = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:3000/preprocess', headers=headers, json=json_data) to   preprocessing_response = requests.post('http://preprocess_service:3000/preprocess', headers=headers, json=json_data) but the same error still remains